# Update IP button twice a day option?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a secure web-based login tool for my software, and for it, i need an "One IP only login" per account.
For that, I need to make the user able to update it's IP twice a day.

```
<h2><strong>Controle</strong> de Acesso</h2>
<div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Activated IP</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipsaved" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $userInfo['iplib']; ?>" disabled readonly/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Actual IP:</label>
            <label><?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?></label>
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to know how can i make a button to update Activated IP from Actual IP, that can only be done twice a day

How can i make this button, and make it able to only 2 changes a day?

Comment: Hey, i'm sorry
Just added it!

Comment: The question is really still not specific. Do you not know the steps needed to do this? (They're pretty obvious! When the user logs in, check their IP against the database. If it's new, check if it's too many changes, if so send an error. Update the database to reflect the new IP count and time.) Or is one of those steps giving you trouble? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the persons ip somewhere such as the database then when someone tries to login and their ip doesn't match whats in the database then it wont work. you can also store the date of when the ip was last stored and update it every 12 hours or something.

But this method isn't really considered secure because its really easy to mimic an ip address of someone else. You can setup 2 factor authentication where when the person tries to login they are sent an sms or email with a 4-6 character verification code and have 20 minute to enter it to be able to login.